# What are the chances that 52 char long Personal Access Token would end in the specific 4 characters?

Tags: probability

So, according to my understanding the PAT in question (for Azure DevOps Services) is 52 chars long and contains only lower case letters and digits, i.e. 36 options per slot.

A naive calculation gives the probability of $1/36^4$. But I wonder if other factors affect it.

For example, the motivation for this question is that the PAT I got a few months back ends with the first name of my wife - **yana**. I wonder how, if at all, this affects the calculation.

Comment: If the probabilities of each letter are independent of the rest, your calculation is correct.

Comment: "*I wonder if other factors affect it*"  Perhaps there are a few notable "bad words" that it will avoid, like common obscenities.  For example words that are commonly referred to in the form "the ___-word."  If this were the case, then probabilities will not in fact be truly independent and to get an exact answer would require knowledge of how these PATs were generated.  Even then, the probability will likely be remarkably close to the naive calculation.

Comment: I speculate that (for example) **vowels** are *disproportionally frequent*.  This is because vowels are used to construct syllables, and syllables promote learning/memorizing the password.  That is, you *mentally speak the password*.

Comment: The PAT is automatically generated by the system. No human involvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is, "What is the probability that this particular PAT would end in my wife's first name", then you are correct, it is $\frac 1{36^4}$ (assuming your information about the generation of the PAT is correct).

But if the question is "How likely is it that such a coincidence would occur", the answer is: they occur *all the time*. Hundreds if not thousands of similiarly rare coincidences occur to people every single day. To understand why, consider

- You would probably be equally impressed if the PAT started with her name instead. So this halves the probability of such a coincidence.
- You would also probably be equally impressed if it had started or ended with your own 4-letter name (at least, the one you used here is 4 letters). And there are likely other 4-letter names that would similarly impressed you. Let me assume that on average people have ~ten 4-letter names that they would have been impressed by. So now the probability of the coincidence is divided by $20$, making it about $1$ in $83981$.
- Azure DevOps Services likely creates many such PATs every day. If we suppose they create $200$ a day on average, then you can expect this coincidence to occur for someone about every $420$ days.

And that is just for a coincidence of the exact same type as the one that occurred for you. There obvious small variations that would greatly increase the number of times it occurs at only moderate changes to the probability, for example, names of different lengths, names occurring elsewhere than the ends, PATs generated by other companies. Add on top of that all the other possibilities for rare-but-recognizable coincidences that could occur, and the fact that there are 8 billion people in the world, and it becomes clear that they are actually common.

Additionally there are a lot of coincidences that seem extremely unlikely, but are much more common than people think. An excellent example of this is discussed in [this Stand-Up Maths video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9-b-QJZdVA) on youtube. (The reason is the assumptions behind the naive probability calculation turn out to be false.)